# sbt returns dependency issue

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a maven project which I am trying to convert to SBT .The maven project works correctly with the dependencies given .But when using the corresponding dependencies in SBT , I am getting sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException for the dependencies which I am not using in the dependencies .

```
 sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.netbeans.api:org-openide-util:RELEASE82
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dileep\.ivy2\local\org.netbeans.api\org-openide-util\RELEASE82\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/netbeans/api/org-openide-util/RELEASE82/org-openide-util-RELEASE82.pom
[error] Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}:${spark.version}
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dileep\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}\${spark.version}\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}/${spark.version}/spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}-${spark.version}.pom
```

This error comes only when adding either of these dependencies.

```
"net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-inference-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
"net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-query-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
```

pom dependencies

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <spark.version>2.2.0</spark.version>
    <sansa.version>0.7.1</sansa.version>
    <jena.version>3.13.1</jena.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-graphx_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache JENA 3.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>${jena.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jena.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
        <version>${jena.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aksw.jena-sparql-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-sparql-api-server-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.18.v20190429</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SANSA RDF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sansa-stack</groupId>
        <artifactId>sansa-rdf-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${sansa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SANSA OWL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sansa-stack</groupId>
        <artifactId>sansa-owl-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${sansa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SANSA Inference -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sansa-stack</groupId>
        <artifactId>sansa-inference-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${sansa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SANSA Querying -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sansa-stack</groupId>
        <artifactId>sansa-query-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${sansa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SANSA ML -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sansa-stack</groupId>
        <artifactId>sansa-ml-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${sansa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
     <version>${spark.version}</version>

     </dependency>
```

SBT file dependencies

```
val scalaLang = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.12"
val sparkCore = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
val sparkGraphx = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "2.2.0"
val sparkSql = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.0"
val sparkAvro = "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.11" % "4.0.0"
val jenaLibs = "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "3.13.1" pomOnly()
val jenaCore = "org.apache.jena" % "jena-core" % "3.13.1"
val jenaArq = "org.apache.jena" % "jena-arq" % "3.13.1"
val jenaSparqlAPI = "org.aksw.jena-sparql-api" % "jena-sparql-api-server-standalone" % "3.13.1-1"
val jettyServer = "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.4.18.v20190429"
val sansaRDF = "net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-rdf-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
val sansaOwl = "net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-owl-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
val sansaInference =  "net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-inference-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
val sansaQuery = "net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-query-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
val sansaML = "net.sansa-stack" % "sansa-ml-spark_2.11" % "0.7.1"
val kafkaClients = "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0"
val sparkSqlKafka = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided"


lazy val SansaQueryExecutor = (project in file("SansaQueryExecutor"))
  .settings(
    name := "SansaQueryExecutor",
/*    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.0"*/
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaLang, sparkCore,sparkGraphx,sparkSql,sparkAvro,jenaLibs,jenaCore,jenaArq,jenaSparqlAPI,jettyServer,sansaRDF,sansaOwl,sansaML,kafkaClients,sparkSqlKafka,/*sansaInference,sansaQuery*/)
    /*libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-avro" % "4.0.0"*/
)
```

Comment: The problem is that the package `org.netbeans.api" % "org-openide-util" % "RELEASE82` is not in the default sbt resolver.
If you look on maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.netbeans.api/org-openide-util you'll see it in the netbeans repo. Unfortunately the repo is quite old and doesn't seems to be maintained very well, so I wasn't able to set it up properly. usually you can set up additionaly resolvers with `resolvers += "name" at "url".
But it didn't work for this one. It seems because of some redirects. maybe you can put it in your local repo by hand.

Comment: @Saskia But this issue does not come up with Maven. It is able to download all the dependencies